How to ensure a Lambda processes only one SQS message at a time?
I am working with AWS Lambda triggered by an SQS queue. The problem is that I don’t know exactly how long each task will take to process. It could take anywhere from 2 minutes to 10 minutes. My Lambda execution timeout is set to 10 minutes, and the SQS visibility timeout is set to 11 minutes.
I have configured the following:

Batch size: 1 (to process one message per invocation)
Reserved concurrency: 1 (to ensure only one Lambda instance runs at a time)

The issue arises when:
A task is completed in less than 10 minutes (e.g., 2 minutes).
The Lambda picks up another task in the same instance, which takes longer (e.g., 10 minutes), causing a timeout.
enter image description here
enter image description here

"The Lambda picks up another task in the same instance" - then you are doing something fundamentally wrong. Your lambda instance must not actively read messages from the queue. The lambda services takes the message and invokes your lambda. There cannot be a case where a second messages is picked up by the same lambda instance and inherits the previous timeout. Yes, lambda instances / execution environments are reused but the time the 1st invocation took has no impact on the time the 2nd has.
Concurrency of 1 and batch size of 1 is the solution you are looking for and will work.


maybe https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/01/aws-lambda-maximum-concurrency-amazon-sqs-event-source/


I agree with @luk2302 -- can you show us your code that receives the messages from the SQS queue?

@JohnRotenstein added the screenshot of code !!

Side-note: When adding code, please add it to your Question as text instead of images.

Can you please explain more about your statement that "The Lambda picks up another task in the same instance"? Are you saying that event.Records contains more than 1 value? If so, it suggests that the Batch Size was not set to 1. Or are you saying that the Lambda function is invoked again with a new set of inputs (but this would mean that the timeout counter is reset to zero)?

What gives you the idea that anything runs into a timeout and that if it runs into a timeout is because of a previously processed message in the same lambda instance?

Oh, sorry, I got it. I was watching the logs and noticed that the same log files started again after finishing one task. I thought the instance was being reused without restarting the clock. However, I’ve now logged context.getRemainingTimeInMillis(), and I see that it’s restarting the timer again. Thanks for your help!
